# How to write an ampersand character in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to parse and modify some HTML.  In certain places, I want to add a non-breaking space entity (&nbsp;) to the HTML.  I assumed I could do it as in this simplified example:

```
Element paragraph = someDocument.select("p").first();
paragraph.text("First sentence.&nbsp; Second sentence.");
```

But Jsoup turns my `&nbsp;` into `&amp;nbsp;` effectively encoding the ampersand itself.  I guess my real question is: how can I manually write an ampersand character to the text of an `Element`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing Element.text. If its html, use .html(String s) instead so, replace your code with

```
Element paragraph = someDocument.select("p").first();
paragraph.html("First sentence.&nbsp; Second sentence.");
```

Comment: This way you dont need to worry about adding other special html characters too

Answer (score 2):

Try using the unicode value for no-breaking space.

```
Element paragraph = someDocument.select("p").first();
paragraph.text("First sentence.\u00a0Second sentence.");
```

Comment: +1. And if you prefer `nbsp` to `00a0`, you can use `org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.getCharacterByName("nbsp")`.

Comment: Using the unicode escape sequence directly in the string doesn't work.  However, `Entities.getCharacterByName(String s)` does work.  Still going with the other answer because I think it is more appropriate to my exact situation.  +1 to ruakh's comment though.  Darn my noobishness.  Can I not +1 the comment?  It seems I voted for it instead . . .